Can't scroll bottomsheet in Android Native App using Appium WebdriverIO
I have tried all the methods to scroll, nothing works for this one app that I am working on. Same scroll methods work on other sample application that I tried.
Also, the scroll only doesn't work on the bottomsheet.
Can anyone tell me what could be the reason?
I have already tried,

await $('android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollToEnd(5)')
await driver.performActions([
{
type: 'pointer',
id: 'finger1',
parameters: { pointerType: 'touch' },
actions: [
{ type: 'pointerMove', duration: 0, x: 333, y: 333 },
{ type: 'pointerDown', button: 0 },
{ type: 'pause', duration: 100 },
{ type: 'pointerMove', duration: 1000, origin: 'pointer', x: 2544, y: 2544 },
{ type: 'pointerUp', button: 0 },
],
},
])
await this.dashboradScreen.touchAction([
'press',
{ action: 'moveTo', element: this.overviewTitle },
'release'
]);


Not sure about webdriverio but It might help you: https://medium.com/@monfared/gestures-in-appium-part4-scroll-vertical-horizontal-search-scroll-element-intoview-6e04972b6dde
